# Bloom filter variant(using only half of it)

Tags: algorithms, hash-tables, hashing, bloom-filters

A Bloom filter is an array $B[1..m]$ of bits, together with a collection of $k$ independent ideal random hash functions $h_1,h_2,...,h_k$. To insert an item $x$ into a Bloom filter, we set $B[h_i(x)] ← 1$ for every index $i$. To test whether an item $x$ belongs to a set represented by a Bloom filter, we check whether $B[h_i(x)] = 1$ for every index $i$. This algorithm always returns True if $x$ is in the set, but may return either True or False when $x$ is not in the set. Thus, there may be false positives, but no false negatives.

If there are n distinct items stored in the Bloom filter, then the probability of a false positive is $(1 − p)k$, where $p ≈ e^{−kn/m}$ is the probability that $B[j] = 0$ for any particular index $j$. In particular, if we set $k = (m/n) ln 2$, then $p = 1/2$, and the probability of a false positive is $(1/2)(m/n) ln 2 ≈ (0.61850)m/n$.

After months spent lovingly crafting a Bloom filter of size m for a set S of n items, using exactly $k = (m/n) ln 2$ hash functions (so p = 1/2), your boss tells you that you must reduce the size of your Bloom filter from m bits down to $m/2$ bits. Unfortunately, you no longer have the original set S, and your company’s product ships tomorrow; you have to do something quick and dirty. Fortunately, your boss has a couple of ideas.

(a)First your boss suggests simply discarding half of the Bloom filter, keeping only the subarray $B[1 .. m/2]$. Describe an algorithm to check whether a given item $x$ is an element of the original set S, using only this smaller Bloom filter. As usual, if $x ∈ S$, your algorithm must return True.

(b) What is the probability that your algorithm returns True when $x ̸∈ S$?

Can I ask for some help for part (a) and (b)? I'm really stuck for that.

Here's what I got so far for (a), given an item $x$, if $b[h_i(x)]=0$ for some $i$, then output FALSE($x \not \in S$). If all $B[h_i(x)] =1 \forall i \in [k]$, this means all the value of the hash function lies in the half of the bloom filter, so we output TRUE. On the other hand, if all $B[h_i(x)] =1$ in the half of the bloom filter, but we don't know about the hashed value of the other discarded half bloom filter, then we still output TRUE.

Is my direction for (a) right? Also, how to approach part (b)?

Comment: Where did you encounter this task?  Please credit the original source of all copied material.

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.  You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.